# Passing Of Objects in scala

Tags: java, function, scala, object

Hey guys i am trying to pass an Object(type Object) that is a combination of a (string+object).
In the function i need to compare the the string with a hash map and accordingly do operations with the attached object.

The code goes like this

```
 Function (srt : Object)
{
 //s is an array of Strings  
  var s = srt.toString.split("+")
  if(s[0]== insert)
    {
    var ne = s[1].asInstanceOf(USERDEFINEDCLASS) //ERROR here
   //do operations
    }
 }

     main()
       {
      var og : className = new className(parameters)
      Function(og ->("insert"))
       }
```

In this code i am getting the error saying it cannot be converted from string to the class object. 
 I am not able to figure out a way of doing it. Can someone help me with this

Comment: This isn't valid Scala code to start with.

Comment: Where does `USERDEFINEDCLASS` comes from?

Comment: I could live with `USERDEFINEDCLASS`, as a illustration. But the rest the program don't even parses under any language I know, not even mixing pieces of the parsers lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure it will help you. Here follows a program with some features you described:

```
class Main{
    class SomeClass(val x:String) { override def toString:String = x }
    def funct(obj:Object) {
        val s=obj.toString.split("+")
        if(s(0) == "a" ) { // assumingn it's a non empty string
            println(obj.asInstanceOf[SomeClass].x)
        }

    }
    def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
        funct(new SomeClass("a+b"))
    }
}
```